# How i can connect two stores in one in Redux

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I need to connect multiple reducers or storage into 1, how can I do that. Since both stores have very different configurations, I don't know how to properly wrap them into one. So far I'm using store for Provider, I would like to use the newStore functionality as well. I would really appreciate help!

```
const persistConfig = {key: "root", storage, version: 1};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);

const newStore = configureStore({
  reducer: persistReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoreActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      }
    })
  }
})

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    global: globalReducer,
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefault) => getDefault().concat(api.middleware),
});
setupListeners(store.dispatch);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(newStore)}> */}
        <App />
      {/* </PersistGate>  */}
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking having multiple stores in redux app is not a recommended pattern, also I don't think merging two stores into one is possible. Maybe worth trying reducer composition first?

> Some valid reasons for using multiple stores in Redux might include:
>
> - Solving a performance issue caused by too frequent updates of some
>   part of the state, when confirmed by profiling the app.
> - Isolating a
>   Redux app as a component in a bigger application, in which case you
>   might want to create a store per root component instance.

Here is [more info on multiple stores](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself)

If you still need to have multiple stores on one page check out [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/92pm9n2kl4?file=/src/index.js)

```
<Provider context={ThemeContext} store={themeStore}>
  <Provider /** context={bookContext} */ store={bookStore}>
    <Theme context={ThemeContext}>
      <Books /** context={bookContext} */ />
    </Theme>
  </Provider>
</Provider>
```

So I would only consider the case for isolating redux app as a component in bigger application or part of app that stands out from rest like admin panel, so you'll still have one store per root component.